# Sonarqube Docker caching doesn't work with .NET application

Tags: .net, git, docker, sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube for my .NET app to analyse the code. To be able to track changes in the project I need to include .git folder to docker image (exclude it from .dockerignore).
But in this case, whenever the .git folder changes (new commit, new push), all caches are invalidated on the command COPY ["nuget.config", "Payouts/"]
Is that a pissibility to exclude .git folder from the "build" stage and include this folder before "sonar end" command?

I tried to do like that:

```
RUN rm -rf .git
```

But, as I understand, since checksum of the folder has already changed, the cache is invalidated as well.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

ENV SONAR_SCANNER_DOTNET_TOOL_VERSION=6.0.0 \
    JDK_VERSION=17
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-$JDK_VERSION-jre \
    && dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version $SONAR_SCANNER_DOTNET_TOOL_VERSION
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

ARG SONAR_PROJECT_KEY="MyProjecteKey"
ARG SONAR_OGRANIZAION_KEY="OrganizationKey"
ARG SONAR_HOST_URL="MyUrl"
ARG SONAR_TOKEN="MyTOken"
ARG BRANCH_NAME="branchName"

dotnet sonarscanner begin \
        /k:"$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY" \
        /o:"$SONAR_OGRANIZAION_KEY" \
        /d:sonar.host.url="$SONAR_HOST_URL" \
        /d:sonar.login="$SONAR_TOKEN" \
        /d:sonar.pullrequest.key="$PULL_REQUEST_ID" \
        /d:sonar.pullrequest.branch="$PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH_NAME_VAR" \
        /d:sonar.pullrequest.base="$PULL_REQUEST_BASE_BRANCH_NAME_VAR"; \

COPY ["nuget.config", "Payouts/"] # cache is invalidated from here
COPY ["Payouts/Payouts.csproj", "Payouts/"]
COPY ["Payouts.Tests/Payouts.Tests.csproj", "Payouts.Tests/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Payouts/Payouts.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "Payouts.Tests/Payouts.Tests.csproj"
COPY . .

RUN dotnet build "Payouts/Payouts.csproj" -c Release --no-restore
RUN dotnet build "Payouts.Tests/Payouts.Tests.csproj" -c Release --no-restore --no-dependencies

RUN dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.token="$SONAR_TOKEN"

WORKDIR /src/Payouts.Tests
RUN dotnet test -c Release --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=Payouts.trx"

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR "/src/Payouts"
RUN dotnet publish "Payouts.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --no-build --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Payouts.dll"]
```